# Which lib did I forget?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, libs

So I'm trying to import an existing app into my eclipse and I'm pretty sure i'm missing an important library. The app I'm trying to import is using a QR scanner and I can't find which QR scanner library to add to make it work.
[image]

I'm only getting errors on activites that has anything to do with QR scanner. Do you have any idea which QR lib am I missing? Or is a problem elsewhere?

Additional info: I searched the whole project folder to find any kind of jar files while importing and I found a folder called "dexedLibs" which contains a bunch of libs and one of them is called portraitqr-240085fd1164d9856f284087ee573e6d, I tried adding it to build path but nothing happened. Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: Press: right-Control + right-shift + O, it will auto import the needed libraries. Cheers.

Comment: If you downloaded the Zxing zip file from the Google Projects, import the `client` folder as a library into your workspace. You can also make a JAR of it and import it. Then reference it to your project.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I downloaded [this](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-2.2.zip) file and there is no client folder in it. Also, how do I reference something to a certain project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GrepCode.com](http://grepcode.com) is an excellent resource for this sort of problem: http://grepcode.com/search/?query=CaptureActivity

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry to bother you again, but could you tell me how to use this site? I'm confused at first, not sure how I should use this website

Comment: @Matthew You can type in the name of any Java project, package, class or method and it will list all the libraries which contain it, in this case I searched for `CaptureActivity` as it's missing from the code you posted.

Comment: @Matthew: You could also use a more conventional search engine, like, say, Google. A search for `CaptureActivity` on Google returns the proper link to [its implementation in the ZXing project](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java?r=1464) as the first hit.